# Selecting one MySQL date with month reduced by one

Tags: sql, datetime, mysqli

I was thinking in a way to improve the following query if possible:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y'), ',', 
       (MONTH(start_date) -1), ',', DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d')) as start_date
FROM PROJECTS
```

I need `start_date` in this format: `dd/mm-1/yyyy`.

Note: I am using an API that use month from 0 to 11, and MySQL uses 1 to 12 – that's why I need *month - 1*.

Comment: Could you post your application code as well? I think that using SQL to work around the 0-1 mismatch is a bad idea.

Comment: I am working just with database. I don't have access to the code at all. Should I say or ask for the backend programmers that there are better practices? Or even in the code, there's no way to get this code better?

Comment: Where are you running that query from, if it is not embedded in some program? In my opinion, it would be cleaner for the query to return a "natural"-looking date (with months 1-12), and for the code that consumes the date to adjust it to the API (months 0-11) as necessary.

Comment: It's a stored procedure. Anyhow, talking about the query itself, there is some improvement that can I do?

Comment: what are you going to do with this Data after you have queried it?  what API are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no workaround then, bad practice as it may be, what you have is functional. I [found this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931106/mysql-my-months-are-current-stored-0-11) that may allow you to convert the column's `date` data type to the 0-11 format. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Removed bad idea. If you really wish to see it just look at the edit history, but it is not a good idea. I'm going back to my original answer.

Comment: I found MySQL raises no error when `CAST` or `CONVERT` as `DATE` is used with the 0-11 format so you should still be able to do date calcs on those too.

Comment: Disclaimer: The `CAST(SUBSTRING(` section is almost wholly adapted from the SO link posted above.

Comment: Using SQL to produce a weirdly formatted date was bad; storing redundant data is even worse, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair point 200_success

Comment: I went ahead and rolled it back.